# directx apply texture

Tags: c++, visual-c++, winapi, directx-9

i found some examples how to apply texture on 2d object but nothing on 3d. if you know any tutorial or you can give me an example that would be greate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about:

- [Texture Coordinates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb206245%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Flexible Vertex Format](http://www.toymaker.info/Games/html/fvf.html)
- [Adding Textures](http://www.directxtutorial.com/Tutorial9/B-Direct3DBasics/dx9B8.aspx)

Also, next time, please take time to search for tutorial contents in the web. It's not hard to search for `DirectX Tutorials` or `Direct3D Tutorials` in Google or your favourite search engine to find these contents ;)

Comment: i was searching for tutorials found some that where not free, bad explained......